# 800V to 250V pulses conversion

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I need to convert 800V output from [Pockels Cell driver](https://vigitek.biz/wp-content/uploads/QBU-BT-manual-en.pdf), at 52 kHz of bandwidth.

Load is capacitive 11pF (drawing a surge current of 100 mA or more), specifically an Electro-Optical Modulator that requires 250V pulses at 52 kHz or lower.

What would be the better solution to transfer 800V differential to 250V single ended?

Best idea comes to my mind is transformers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the load is 11 pF, the easiest solution is to use a capacitive dropper. So, if you used 11 pF in series with the 11 pF Pockels cell, the voltage on the cell would be halved from 800 volts to 400 volts but, you would have to add an extra 5.5 pF in parallel with the series Pockels cell and 11 pF to ensure that the overall load seen by the generator remains at 11 pF.

That's the general idea and to get 250 volts across the cell needs a series capacitance of 4.5 pF in series with the cell. This has a net capacitance of 3.193 pF and, overall, in parallel with the series pair you will need a further 7.807 pF in parallel to maintain the correct load (11 pF) to the generator.

You could use a transformer but, it might alter the characteristic shape of the applied pulse making the cell operate incorrectly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBgcsy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I think it’s an elegant solution.